# How to make a Discord Bot repeat and simulate a user reply?

Tags: python, discord.py

Thanks in advance to anyone reading this

I wanted to make my discord bot follow a user reply function:

[this is how I wanted it to be like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOQuV.png)

Apologies for not using a real bot for the example. I can't open nor run the code while running Opera.

Here's the code I've made so far

```
    if "ngab" in message.content or "Ngab" in message.content or "NGAB" in message.content:
        content=message.content.lower()
        final=content.replace("ngab",":ng::ab:")
        if len(final)<=2000:
            await message.delete()        
            await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}: {final}')
        else:
            await message.reply(f"too long :ng::ab: {message.author.mention}")
```

When I reply to another user with "ngab" in it, the bot only repeats the contents of the message, but I wanted it to reply as if it was the message I sent.

I do not know how to achieve the desired results, all I know is how to make the bot reply to the corresponding message.

Appreciate anyone that can help out, apologies for any mistakes I made in this question, first time asker here. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, you have to check if the message has a reference.

```
if len(final)<=2000:
            ref = message.reference
            await message.delete()        
            await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}: {final}', reference=reference)
        else:
            await message.reply(f"too long :ng::ab: {message.author.mention}")
```

We find if the message has any reference(if it is a reply) and then reply to that message.

### References:

- [message.reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=reference#discord.Message.reference)